# Spring data elasticsearch + arangodb + spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, arangodb, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to add spring-data-elasticsearch to spring boot project but after it I'm getting creating beans errors. I think that could happening because of conflicts with arangodb or webflux dempendencies. How colud I solve this problem?

Comment: I wonder how many different error messages exist for this?

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException, org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException and java.lang.NullPointerException for each bean that apllication try to create. I resolve this by moveing elasticsearch to separated project but answer for this issue could be useful for someone else.